# Play2: Difference between appDependencies and libraryDependencies?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

in a **Playframework 2 App (2.2.x)** there is a *build.sbt* file. In this file one should specify the dependencies the app has.

Some docs write about

```
val appDependencies = Seq(put dependencies here)
```

and in the default there is a

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(put dependencies here)
```

When to take what?
What is the difference between appDependencies and libraryDependencies?

Cheers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you are mixing up sbt `build.sbt` and `Build.scala` definitions (see [sbt Build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html)).

`libraryDependencies` is a key defined by sbt you can use in `build.sbt` files (which are basically key-value-stores). However, there is no predefined `appDependencies` key.

The example you gave

```
val appDependencies = Seq(put dependencies here)
```

is just a vanilla variable that could have any arbitrary name. You could as well name it `dependenciesForTehLulz`. The reason is that this variable is used to pass the dependencies to the Project definition constructor later, and its name simply doesn't matter:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, **appDependencies**).settings(
    ...
)
```

This is only possible in `Build.scala`-style project definitions.